# TextBox: bound to double, converted via IMultiValueConverter: not updated when value changed in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, caliburn.micro, imultivalueconverter

I am using Caliburn.Micro.

In my View I have a `TextBox` Binded to `double X` and a `Button` which *alters* the value of *X* in my ViewModel.

```
public void ButtonPressed()
    {
        X = AnObject.GetDouble;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => X);
    }

    public double X { get; set; }
```

**My Goal** is to limit the number of decimals that is displayed. This number, is configurable in the application and therefore available as a Property of AnObject. Therefore I have defined a `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format(values[1].ToString(), values[0]);
    }
```

and defined my TextBox as follows:

```
<TextBox>
     <TextBox.Text>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource coordinateConverter}" >
                 <Binding Path="X" />
                 <Binding Path="AnObject.FormatNumberOfDecimals" />
           </MultiBinding>
     </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**What works:** The initial value  of X, zero, is being formatted correctly.

**What doesn't work:** When the button is pressed, the new value is not being displayed in the TextBox.

Suggestions that don't use IMultiValueConverter are welcome as well.

Comment: Try setting the binding mode to TwoWay.

Comment: Is it working the other way? Do you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` behind the class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my `string FormatNumberOfDecimals`should be of format `{0:0.0000}` instead of `0.00000`.

`0.0000` works on ContentStringFormat of a Label and does not cause Exceptions in my Visual Studio Designer but apparently does not work on a TextBox when using `String.Format()`.

`{0:0.0000}` works on ContentStringFormat of a Label and on my TextBox using `String.Format()`. Unfortunately, my Visual Studio Design view is now throwing an exception and of no use for the View with my TextBox.

```
System.FormatException
Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0)
```

Comment: pls check the difference between ContentStringFormat and StringFormat - there are some stackoverflow posts to that

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems like this in the past too, where a `MultiConverter` will not automatically update when one of the bound values updates.

Since you are not using a binding for your 2nd value, you can switch to a single `IValueConverter`, and pass your format in as the `ConverterParameter`

Or simply use the `StringFormat` property of the binding

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding X, StringFormat=D4}" />
```

Note that if you are binding the `Content` property instead of the `Text` property, such as on a `Label`, the `StringFormat` property of the binding won't work and you need to set the Label's `ContentStringFormat` property instead.

Comment: My format is dynamically altered, so I would need to pass a binding to ConverterParameter of which I was under the impression it was impossible.

Answer (score -1):

that is work

decimal debit = 0;
decimal credit = 0;

```
        decimal.TryParse(values[0].ToString(), out debit);
        decimal.TryParse(values[1].ToString(), out credit);

        decimal total = debit - credit;

        return total.ToString("0.00"); // string form
```